# How to disable mat drop down option from one to two?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular5

TS Code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';

/**
 * @title Basic use of `<table mat-table>`
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
 timeSelection1='';
 timeSelection2=''; 

  resTimePeriodData= [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4"
  ] 
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 ">
        <!-- DROP DOWN FOR CURRENT TIME PERIOD -->
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select placeholder="Current Time Period" multiple 
 name="select1" [(ngModel)]="timeSelection1" (ngModelChange)="onchange()" >
                <mat-option *ngFor="
 let time1 of resTimePeriodData
 " [value]="time1">{{ time1 }}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <mat-form-field >
            <!-- DROP DOWN FOR PREVIOUS TIME PERIOD -->
            <mat-select  placeholder="Previous Time Period" multiple name="select2" [(ngModel)]="timeSelection2" >
                <mat-option *ngFor="
  let time2 of resTimePeriodData
 " [value]="time2">{{ time2 }}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to disable 1st selected element to drop down two that element selected in the dropdown one.
If I select 3 in the dropdown one and I select 2 in dropdown two and if I want to select 2 from the dropdown one I will get selected and both drop down having the same option!

The code that I tried [`StackBlitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dropdown12345677709?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html)

Comment: Are you looking for this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/dropdown12345677709-yapm2r

Comment: yes exactly @PrashantPimpale you are always right!
 could you put this in answer section? thanks you so much! :)

Comment: Glad it helps..!

Comment: Hi @PrashantPimpale if u select second drop down option and same option if u select in first drop down how to deselect that option! ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 ">
        <!-- DROP DOWN FOR CURRENT TIME PERIOD -->
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select [(value)]="selected" placeholder="Current Time Period" multiple name="select1" [(ngModel)]="timeSelection1">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let time1 of resTimePeriodData" [value]="time1">{{ time1 }}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <mat-form-field>
            <!-- DROP DOWN FOR PREVIOUS TIME PERIOD -->
            <mat-select placeholder="Previous Time Period" multiple name="select2" [(ngModel)]="timeSelection2">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let time2 of resTimePeriodData" [value]="time2" [disabled]="isDisable(time2)">{{ time2 }}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
isDisable(obj) {
   var index = this.selected.indexOf(obj);
   if (index == -1) {
      return false;
   }
   else {
     return true;
   }
}
```

You can also try to improve the existing code!

[`Stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dropdown12345677709-yapm2r)

Comment: Hi @Prashant Pimple if u select second drop down option and same option if u select in first drop down how to deselect that option! ?

Comment: @JustTeachMe it this what do you want? --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/dropdown12345677709-yapm2r

Answer (score 0):

The value is being interpereted as a number. You can compare the time options in the disabled attribute using to string:

```
<mat-option [disabled]="time2.toString() === timeSelection1.toString()" *ngFor="
  let time2 of resTimePeriodData
 " [value]="time2">{{ time2 }}</mat-option>
```

I would recommend using numbers only though.

Comment: thanks but this is working for only one element! what about for multiple elements?